# Difference between Web Application and ReSTful Application?

Tags: rest, web-applications

What is the Difference between Web Application and ReSTful Application? Please Give some Example?

Comment: have a look at my answer to a similar question https://stackoverflow.com/a/58644835/651827

Answer (score 0):

RESTful service is a type of Web Application. Web Application can be a service, site, game, etc.

This [picture](https://www.mindmeister.com/961863251/types-of-web-based-application) is not what I wanted, but it shows many types of Web Applications.

Comment: Well while shopping from Flipkart we are using payment system like phonepay app or google pay.So is this a type of restful web application?

Comment: while we are developing spring boot application like spring boot crud application we use restful to access data from sql database.so is this the proper representation of restful application?